# I can not hide keyboard by pressing return key

Tags: iphone, ios, resignfirstresponder

I have tried this:

In `.h` file :

```
    @interface TouchLabelViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *aTextField;        
-(IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender;
```

In `.m` File :

```
-(IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender{
    [(UITextField*)sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

And also tried this.

In `.h` file :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    aTextField.delegate = self;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *aTextField;
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;
```

In `.m` file:

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    [aTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

But still whenever I touch return key it does not hide keyboard.

Comment: Did you set the UITextField delegate properly?

Comment: Are you using UITextField and not UITextView by mistake?

Comment: have you assigned the delegate? `keyboard.delegate = self;`

Comment: Instead of [aTextField resignFirstResponder]; please use [textField resignFirstResponder]; It'll work.

Comment: @chetan can you tell me the way of your are showing current view.just for more explaination

Comment: @kamarshad ,i have a label in first view and when user will touch that label than second view will appear and in that view i have this textfield.

Comment: @chetan thanks ,are you  presenting that second view modally? if so then see my `Edit`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can take Advantage of these(delegate) methods when you set the delegate  to the Textfield.

YOu should Check your delegate whether  you have set the delegate to the Textfield

set this In your `.h` Class

```
     YourViewController :   UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Now Where you created the TextField set delegate like below

```
       myTextField.delegate = self;
```

And further do same as you were doing

```
 -(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
     [textField resignFirstResponder];
     return YES;
  }
```

**EDIT: In case if you were presenting the Current as  `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` 
 Presentation modes may keep the keyboard visible when not required.
 Default implementation affects UIModalPresentationFormSheet visibility.that's why need to  overriding it for hiding keyboard**

```
  - (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal 
 {
   return NO; 
 }
```

Comment: actually i am not presentModalViewController ,and adding subview into my view your EDIT code give me hint that i have to presentModalViewController,when i have done it it was work like charm,thanx.

Comment: Thanks for the note about `-disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal`.

Answer (score 2):

first set delegate for TextField

```
aTextField.delegate = self;

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
     [textField resignFirstResponder];
    //[aTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your UITextField an outlet and attach it in your XIB file and then set the delegate and in that write the code:

`[texfieldName resignFirstResponder];`

This will work.

Answer (score 1):

Just implement the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` in the .m file as shown below

```
@interface xyzViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

`xyzViewController` will be the name of your view controller. Use this code:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

give the delegate to your `UITextField`

like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    yourTextField.delegate = self;//
}
```

and in Delegate method..

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
     [textField resignFirstResponder];
     return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the `Delegate` in `UITextField` in XIB or Programatically.

```
 -(IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender
{
    [your_textfield resignFirstResponder]; // your_textfield is an UITextField
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the UITextField You can do it like this

In .h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

In .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   textField.delegate = self;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

And For the UITextView You can do it like this

In .h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate>
```

In .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   textView.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```